# How to quit a wit.ai story which is looped back from the end?

Tags: wit.ai

I have three stories in my wit.ai app:

```
- order_pizza: typical pizza ordering with size and toppings
- reserve_table: book a table for a specific date and time
- fav_topping: query favourite pizza topping from historical data by date
```

The third one, fav_topping is a bit special. The user can ask like 'What was my favourite topping in June?'. And after getting the answer, can ask again by changing the date like 'Hm, and in July?'.

More formally: Let's say I have a story with multiple entities (X and Y). The user asks a question with a couple of params (a for X and b for Y), and gets the answer. Than asks again (c for X), and my bot gives an answer by mixing the current params with the previous ones (c for X and b for Y).

To handle this I looped back my fav_topping story from the to the beginning:
[fav_topping story with a loop-back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yCRR.png)

Works perfectly but I have a problem. It never ends. So can't stop it, the user can't change the topic. Here is a log from my node.js client, using the interactive mode:

```
> What was my favourite topping in June?
fav_topping
context in: {}
entities in: {"contact":[{"confidence":0.9965486088458536,"type":"value","value":"my","suggested":true}],"datetime":[{"confidence":0.9954243915206602,"type":"value","value":"2017-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month","values":[{"type":"value","value":"2017-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month"},{"type":"value","value":"2018-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month"},{"type":"value","value":"2019-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month"}]}],"intent":[{"confidence":0.9969200405818317,"value":"fav_topping"}]}
context out is: {"ft_answer":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) *"}
sending... {"text":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
> and in June?
fav_topping
context in: {"ft_answer":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
entities in: {"datetime":[{"confidence":0.994470434703695,"type":"value","value":"2017-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month","values":[{"type":"value","value":"2017-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month"},{"type":"value","value":"2018-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month"},{"type":"value","value":"2019-06-01T00:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"month"}]}]}
context out is: {"ft_answer":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
sending... {"text":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
> OK, I want a normal pizza with tomato and pepperoni
fav_topping
context in: {"ft_answer":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
entities in: {"contact":[{"confidence":0.5452832324099028,"type":"value","value":"I","suggested":true}],"pizza_size":[{"confidence":0.9769454518025678,"type":"value","value":"middle"}],"pizza_topping":[{"confidence":0.9934795348369287,"type":"value","value":"tomato"},{"confidence":0.9505825366331593,"type":"value","value":"pepperoni"}],"intent":[{"confidence":0.6669035510798399,"value":"order_pizza"}]}
context out is: {"ft_answer":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
sending... {"text":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
> Book me a table for 5 persons at 9pm
fav_topping
context in: {"ft_answer":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
entities in: {"contact":[{"confidence":0.8387365394318869,"type":"value","value":"me","suggested":true}],"number":[{"confidence":1,"type":"value","value":5}],"datetime":[{"confidence":1,"type":"value","value":"2016-07-07T21:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"hour","values":[{"type":"value","value":"2016-07-07T21:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"hour"},{"type":"value","value":"2016-07-08T21:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"hour"},{"type":"value","value":"2016-07-09T21:00:00.000-07:00","grain":"hour"}]}],"intent":[{"confidence":0.9997353858626356,"value":"reserve_table"}]}
context out is: {"ft_answer":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) "}
sending... {"text":"Your favourite topping was tomato for sure :) *"}
```

The question is: how can I tell manually/programatically to the BE to finish the story? OR, how can I setup my stories to handle the switch?

One more note: as you can see in my log that the BE understands well the user started a new topic (recognised that the intent changed to 'order_pizza' and 'reserve_table'). Maybe could help a lot if I could define explicitly the intent for the story. What do you think? (not a big change to what we have now: defining the first sentence of the story)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the detailed explanation. This is a currently limitation of Bot Engine and we are working on a more elegant way to cover this. In the meantime, you probably want to delete the "ft_answer" context key when the intent is not "fav_topping".

**More info on the context**

Wit reads the context to make prediction of the next step. We never update the context on our side. You would use action on your side to update keys in the context. These keys can in turn influence the prediction based on the stories but also to build Bot answers via variable. Wit use the current context (keys only for now), the previous states of the context (at interaction N-1, N-2….) but also the user message (trait entities) to predict the next action.

Comment: thanks for the hint. Currently I'm working on something similar, but doing this much deeper - as ktsakas recommended here https://github.com/wit-ai/wit/issues/258. After calling the first converse I check if we are in the same intent OR not. If not, I will drop the session, and send in the same text with a fresh session. Works quite well.